# Is it possible to determine the alphabets from <path> elements in svg

Tags: svg

So I found an extension using the following code for captcha busting.
Sample Captcha : https://svgur.com/s/Xjm

```
var fs = require('fs')
var atob = require('atob');
var model = "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"

var parsed_model = JSON.parse(atob(model))

const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const { window } = new JSDOM("");
const $ = require("jquery")(window);
vals = []
var svg = fs.readFileSync('./test.svg', { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' })
$(svg).find('path').each(
    (_, p) => {
        idx = parseInt($(p).attr("d").split(".")[0].replace("M", ""))
        vals.push(idx)
    }
)
var sorted = [...vals].sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; })
var solution = ['', '', '', '', '']

$(svg).find('path').each(
    (idx, p) => {
        var pattern = $(p).attr('d').replace(/[\d\.\s]/g, "")

        solution[sorted.indexOf(vals[idx])] = parsed_model[pattern]
    })

console.log(solution.join(""))
```

I understand what the code does, my question is does the sequence of these path commands `MMLCQ...` remain the same for characters(a-zA0-9) in all SVG images? or does this work only because of the way these captchas were generated. Can someone point me to the correct resource for this?

PS I don't know much about svgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "no".  This is just for one font.  "M" is "move to", "L" is "draw line to", "Q" is "draw quadratic curve to".  They have removed all the numbers that specify the coordinates.  They're guessing that a sequence of "move, line, line, quadratic, line line, quadratic, etc." is going to represent the digit "1".  Clearly, that's only going to be true for a very few fonts.

Most captchas are bitmaps, not SVGs.  SVGs are too easy to parse.